# Print OLS regression summary to text file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am running OLS regression using `pandas.stats.api.ols` using a `groupby` with the following code:

```
from pandas.stats.api import ols
df=pd.read_csv(r'F:\file.csv')

result=df.groupby(['FID']).apply(lambda d: ols(y=d.loc[:, 'MEAN'], x=d.loc[:, ['Accum_Prcp', 'Accum_HDD']]))
for i in result:
    x=pd.DataFrame({'FID':i.index, 'delete':i.values})
    frame = pd.concat([x,DataFrame(x['delete'].tolist())], axis=1, join='outer')
    del frame['delete']
    print frame
```

but this returns the error:

```
AttributeError: 'OLS' object has no attribute 'index'
```

I have about 2,000 items in my group by and when I print each one out they look something like this:

-

```
------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~ <Accum_Prcp> + <Accum_HDD> + <intercept>

Number of Observations:         79
Number of Degrees of Freedom:   3

R-squared:         0.1242
Adj R-squared:     0.1012

Rmse:              0.1929

F-stat (2, 76):     5.3890, p-value:     0.0065

Degrees of Freedom: model 2, resid 76

-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
      Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Accum_Prcp     0.0009     0.0003       3.28     0.0016     0.0004     0.0015
     Accum_HDD     0.0000     0.0000       1.98     0.0516     0.0000     0.0000
     intercept     0.4750     0.0811       5.86     0.0000     0.3161     0.6340
---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------
```

I want to be able to export each one to a csv so that I can view them individually.

Comment: I believe the `ols.summary()` is actually output as text, not as a `DataFrame`. I've usually resorted to printing to one or more text files for storage.

Comment: when I try something like: `for i in result: i.to_csv(os.path.join(outpath, i +'.csv')` it returns `AttributeError: 'OLS' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`

Comment: Which `OLS` routine are you using? `statsmodels`?

Comment: I should have clarified that, I'm using `pandas.stats.api`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to write out the `result` of `pandas.stats.api.ols`, use a text file to match the output format, for instance:

```
from pandas.stats.api import ols
grps = df.groupby(['FID'])
for fid, grp in grps:
    result = ols(y=grp.loc[:, 'MEAN'], x=grp.loc[:, ['Accum_Prcp', 'Accum_HDD']])

    text_file = open("Output {}.txt".format(fid), "w")
    text_file.write(result.summary)
    text_file.close()
```

Comment: this returned,  `File "F:/python codes/OLS_regress.py", line 35, in <module>
    text_file.write(result)

TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object`

Comment: added `.summary()` to `result`, which should be an `OLS` object with that methods, which in turn produces the text output. See https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/stats/ols.py

Comment: hmm, still returns 
  `File "F:/python codes/OLS_regress.py", line 35, in <module>
    text_file.write(result.summary())

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`, Ill keep playing around with it though

Comment: It's a property, not method, so goes without the `()`, see update.

Comment: For `statsmodels` `0.8.0`, there is `result.summary().as_text()`.

Answer (score 11):

As of `statsmodels 0.9`, the [`Summary` class supports export](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary.html) to multiple formats, including CSV and text:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

dat = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Guerry", "HistData").data
results = smf.ols('Lottery ~ Literacy + np.log(Pop1831)', data=dat).fit()

with open('summary.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(results.summary().as_text())

with open('summary.csv', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(results.summary().as_csv())
```

The output of `as_csv()` is not machine-readable. Dumping `results` parameters with `repr()` would be.